# Probability current for a one dimensional step potential for a reflected wave

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, scattering

I've been following the step potential problem from my textbook and I've got the set of equations right which are:

$$\psi_1 = A_1\left(e^{ik_{1}x} + \frac{k_{1} - k_{2}}{k_{1} + k_{2}}e^{-ik_{1}x}\right)$$

$$\psi_2 = A_1 \frac{2k_{1}}{k_{1} + k_{2}}e^{ik_{2}x} $$

The first term in $\psi_1$ is the incident wave, the second term is  the reflected wave, whereas in $\psi_2$ we have the transmitted wave.

The variables are arranged like this:

$$\ k_1 = \frac{\sqrt{2mE}}{\hbar}  $$

$$\ k_2 = \frac{\sqrt{2m(E-V_{0})}}{\hbar} $$

$$\ \frac{B_1}{A_1} = \frac{k_{1}-k_{2}}{k_{1}+k_{2}} $$

$$\ \frac{A_2}{A_1} = \frac{2k_1}{k_{1}+k_{2}} $$

Now, I've been asked to calculate the probability current using the equation from the textbook:

$$\ j = \frac{i\hbar}{2m}\left(\psi \frac{d \psi^{*}}{dx} - \psi^{*}\frac{d \psi}{dx}\right)$$

$\ *$ is associated with the complex conjugate.

For the incident and transmitted wave I did not have any problems with calculations but when I try to calculate the reflected wave I have this issue:

$$\ j_R = \frac{i\hbar}{2m}\left(A_{1}\frac{k_{1} - k_{2}}{k_{1} + k_{2}}e^{-ik_{1}x} \cdot A_{1}\frac{k_{1} - k_{2}}{k_{1} + k_{2}}ik_{1}e^{ik_{1}x}-\left(\ A_{1}\frac{k_{1} - k_{2}}{k_{1} + k_{2}}e^{ik_{1}x} \cdot -A_{1}\frac{k_{1} - k_{2}}{k_{1} + k_{2}}ik_{1}e^{-ik_{1}x} \right)\right)$$ $$= \frac{i\hbar}{2m}2A_{1}^{2}\left(\frac{k_{1} - k_{2}}{k_{1} + k_{2}}\right)^{2}ik_{1}= -\frac{\hbar}{m}A_{1}^{2}\left(\frac{k_{1} - k_{2}}{k_{1} + k_{2}}\right)^{2}k_{1} $$

The probability current is negative, which is not the case in my textbook where the listed answer is:

$$\frac{\hbar}{m}A_{1}^{2}\left(\frac{k_{1} - k_{2}}{k_{1} + k_{2}}\right)^{2}k_{1} $$

I just have no idea how the probability current can be negative and what could be the possible cause for my error?

Comment: The reflected particle is moving in the opposite direction to the others, right?

Comment: Exactly, this wikipedia picture could be of some help to visualize it https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solution_of_Schr%C3%B6dinger_equation_for_a_step_potential#/media/File:Qm_step_pot_temp.png

Comment: So why is it surprising that the current has the opposite sign to the others?

Comment: Then when we calculate the reflection coefficient $\ R$ and the transmission coefficient $\ T$ how can we show that $\ T + R = 1$ if there is a minus sign in $\ R$?

Comment: You might want to check how the reflection and transmission coefficients are defined. The coefficients should be positive even if the (component of) the probability current is negative.

Comment: From what I understand the reflection coefficient is defined as: $\ R = \frac{j_{ref}}{j_{inc}} $, since the probability current is a vector, we have to take into account its magnitude ... So this is where my mistake lies in? I didn't take the magnitudes?